# Why can't I see my device when plugged into a type-c or other USB port?

Tags: usb-drive, ssd

It's an external 2TB Sandisk device I'm using for backing-up. Not recognized.It works on other Distros. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems I asked my question prematurely. As it turned out, I contacted the Intel site regarding my NUC11PHi7C and there is, in fact, a potential driver/update issue embedded in my NUC. The problem of the Thunderbolt ports not being recognized after some use is not unique to mine. Apparently there are other NUCs that are affected. Fortunately I had another identical NUC in which I attempted, successfully, to install EOS. My apology for stirring-up a potential concern. Best, Geo57